# @Schedule with CDI error:Could not get current FacesContext

Tags: java, ejb, scheduled-tasks, cdi

I'm trying to make a scheduler with the use of CDI

**My EJB Scheduler**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;    
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

import br.com.timbrasil.bluemonster.csr.Crawler;

@Singleton
//@Startup
public class Scheduler {

    @Inject
    private Crawler crawler;

    //TODO https://java.net/jira/browse/EJB_SPEC-1
    @Schedule(hour="*",minute="*/1",second="0")
    public void downloadCsr() {
        System.out.println("Iniciando download dos CSRS");

        LocalDateTime dataInicial = LocalDateTime.now().minusWeeks(1);
        LocalDateTime dataFinal = LocalDateTime.now();

        try {
            crawler.Download(dataInicial, dataFinal);
            System.out.println("CSRs baixados");

            System.out.println("CSRs adicionados");
        } catch (LoginException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I've also tried changing from `import javax.ejb.Singleton` to `import javax.inject.Singleton` as at first made more sense to me, but using `import javax.inject.Singleton` would not even trigger the task.

Also tried to use `@Singleton` with `@ApplicationScoped` (which made even less sense), and `@Dependent`. With or without the `@Dependent` i'm getting the error.

The Crawler that is being called:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import com.byteslounge.cdi.annotation.Property;

@RequestScoped
@Named
public class Crawler {

    @Inject
    private FirefoxDriver driver;


    @Property(value = "csr.login",resourceBundleBaseName="br.com.timbrasil.bluemonster.properties.csronline")
    private String usuario;

    @Property(value = "csr.senha",resourceBundleBaseName="br.com.timbrasil.bluemonster.properties.csronline")
    private String senha;

    public void Download(LocalDateTime dataInicial, LocalDateTime dataFinal)
            throws LoginException {

        driver.get("https://companytoacess.net");

        // Encontra o elemento para inserir o usuario
        WebElement webUsuario = getElementByLocator(By.name("USER"), driver);
        // Insere o usuario
        webUsuario.sendKeys(usuario);

        // Encontra o elemento para inserir a senha
        WebElement webSenha = getElementByLocator(By.name("PASSWORD"), driver);
        // Insere a senha
        webSenha.sendKeys(senha);

        // Acha o bot�o de login e clica
        WebElement button = getElementByLocator(By.name("IMAGE1"), driver);
        button.click();

    }

}
```

Once the `crawler.Download(dataInicial, dataFinal);` line is hit, the Firefox is opened(as it should due to Firefox driver), but then i get the following error:

```
13:58:45,069 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 8) Iniciando download dos CSRS
13:58:45,073 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 8) JBAS014120: Error invoking timeout for timer: [id=2b3fc9c1-d912-40bc-90c4-acf27cd621d0 timedObjectId=blueMonster.blueMonster.Scheduler auto-timer?:true persistent?:true timerService=org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl@116538e1 initialExpiration=null intervalDuration(in milli sec)=0 nextExpiration=Thu Jan 29 13:59:00 BRST 2015 timerState=ACTIVE info=null: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not get current FacesContext
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.TimerCMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(TimerCMTTxInterceptor.java:53) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:340) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:95) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [wildfly-ee-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:448) [wildfly-security-manager-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimedObjectInvokerImpl.callTimeout(TimedObjectInvokerImpl.java:104) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.task.CalendarTimerTask.callTimeout(CalendarTimerTask.java:61) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.task.TimerTask.run(TimerTask.java:168) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final.jar:2.1.1.Final]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not get current FacesContext
    at com.byteslounge.cdi.resolver.locale.JSFLocaleResolver.getLocale(JSFLocaleResolver.java:35)
    at com.byteslounge.cdi.resolver.bean.PropertyResolverBean.resolveProperty(PropertyResolverBean.java:129)
    at com.byteslounge.cdi.resolver.PropertyResolverInjectionTarget.inject(PropertyResolverInjectionTarget.java:99)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:150)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:98)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:78)
    at br.com.timbrasil.bluemonster.csr.Crawler$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.Download(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.timbrasil.scheduler.Scheduler.downloadCsr(Scheduler.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52) [wildfly-ee-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:61) [wildfly-ee-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:95) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:61) [wildfly-ee-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:61) [wildfly-ee-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.concurrency.ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.processInvocation(ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.java:104) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45) [wildfly-ee-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [wildfly-ee-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.processInvocation(SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.java:52) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:273) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    ... 32 more

13:58:45,085 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 8) JBAS014121: Timer: [id=2b3fc9c1-d912-40bc-90c4-acf27cd621d0 timedObjectId=blueMonster.blueMonster.Scheduler auto-timer?:true persistent?:true timerService=org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl@116538e1 initialExpiration=null intervalDuration(in milli sec)=0 nextExpiration=Thu Jan 29 13:59:00 BRST 2015 timerState=ACTIVE info=null will be retried
13:58:45,085 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 8) JBAS014123: Retrying timeout for timer: [id=2b3fc9c1-d912-40bc-90c4-acf27cd621d0 timedObjectId=blueMonster.blueMonster.Scheduler auto-timer?:true persistent?:true timerService=org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl@116538e1 initialExpiration=null intervalDuration(in milli sec)=0 nextExpiration=Thu Jan 29 13:59:00 BRST 2015 timerState=ACTIVE info=null
13:58:46,955 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 8) Iniciando download dos CSRS
13:58:46,958 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 8) JBAS014122: Error during retrying timeout for timer: [id=2b3fc9c1-d912-40bc-90c4-acf27cd621d0 timedObjectId=blueMonster.blueMonster.Scheduler auto-timer?:true persistent?:true timerService=org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl@116538e1 initialExpiration=null intervalDuration(in milli sec)=0 nextExpiration=Thu Jan 29 13:59:00 BRST 2015 timerState=RETRY_TIMEOUT info=null: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not get current FacesContext
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.TimerCMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(TimerCMTTxInterceptor.java:53) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:340) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:95) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [wildfly-ee-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:448) [wildfly-security-manager-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimedObjectInvokerImpl.callTimeout(TimedObjectInvokerImpl.java:104) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.task.CalendarTimerTask.callTimeout(CalendarTimerTask.java:61) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.task.TimerTask.retryTimeout(TimerTask.java:219) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.task.TimerTask.run(TimerTask.java:176) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final.jar:2.1.1.Final]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not get current FacesContext
    at com.byteslounge.cdi.resolver.locale.JSFLocaleResolver.getLocale(JSFLocaleResolver.java:35)
    at com.byteslounge.cdi.resolver.bean.PropertyResolverBean.resolveProperty(PropertyResolverBean.java:129)
    at com.byteslounge.cdi.resolver.PropertyResolverInjectionTarget.inject(PropertyResolverInjectionTarget.java:99)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:150)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:98)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:78)
    at br.com.timbrasil.bluemonster.csr.Crawler$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.Download(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.timbrasil.scheduler.Scheduler.downloadCsr(Scheduler.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52) [wildfly-ee-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:61) [wildfly-ee-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:95) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:61) [wildfly-ee-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:61) [wildfly-ee-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.concurrency.ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.processInvocation(ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.java:104) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45) [wildfly-ee-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [wildfly-ee-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.processInvocation(SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.java:52) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309) [jboss-invocation-1.2.1.Final.jar:1.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:273) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    ... 33 more
```

If i call the Download() method from the Class Crawler using a JSF for example i have no problem at all.

I also tried to remove the `@Inject` and use `private Crawler crawler = new Crawler();` it worked, but then CDI can't inject the FirefoxDriver on the Crawler, since its not being held by CDI itself.

After some digging i ended on these:
https://java.net/jira/browse/EJB_SPEC-1
http://alpengeist-de.blogspot.com.br/2011/10/cdi-events-solve-fancy-problems_21.html

Comment: @hwellmann I truly don't understand exactly how they interact, especially cdi with ejb, that's exactly why I'm asking why it doesn't work

Comment: It seems you're plugging together code snippets from various sources without a clear understanding of what they're doing, and now your asking for help without even posting the relevant bits. That's not the way to post good questions or to obtain good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this `@Property` stuff indirectly accesses the JSF `FacesContext` to determine the current locale. However, there is no current `FacesContext` when your crawler is invoked by a scheduler.

For every JSF request, the CDI request scope is active, but the converse is not true. For scheduler or timeout methods, the CDI request scope is active, but there is no current JSF request.

Comment: And that's exactly what happened. I just assumed that the framework for @Property would be pretty straightforward but it wasn't, after removing it the error is gone, a few other non related problems, but i'll dig into it.

Thank you either way